# How do I force gitlab runner to use the host's domain name instead of ip address?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

My company has a bitnami gitlab installation that we self-host. While I manage the gitlab installation, I am not an expert on it by any stretch. A few months back, I configured a project to use a gitlab runner in order to perform unit tests when the project is committed.

Today, when I pushed a commit, the gitlab runner tried to pull from the ip address using ssl. How do I tell it to pull the commit using the domain name?

I want it to use `https://gitlab.ourcompany.com` but it is using `https://10.1.3.3`

NOTE: not our real ip address or host name:

```
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/full-stack/apigw/.git/
fatal: unable to access 'https://10.1.2.3/full-stack/apigw.git/': SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name '10.1.2.3'
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer after posting the question. Leaving both here for others.

It turns out that our gitlab.rb config file had the external_url set incorrectly. Here are the steps to change that:

**/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb**

```rb
# other entries omitted for brevity
# was external_url 'https://10.1.2.3'

external_url 'https://gitlab.ourcompany.com'
```

Then reload your settings:
`sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`